# How to rename a column using data from a different data frame

Tags: r, multiple-columns, rename

I am doing differential expression analysis on RNA-Seq data. I have generated a counts table and would like to change the column names based on data in my "samples" dataframe to make it easier to read.

This is a portion of my "counts" dataframe generated:

```
                  X140624_I266.4MKD.L1.201   X140624_I266.4MKD.L1.202
gene1                                    0                          0
gene2                                   97                         74
```

This is a portion of my "samples" dataframe:

```
title                                                   id
140718_I266_FCC4RDRACXX_L1_RHUMdztTAAKSRAAPEI-215       GSM2475317
140718_I266_FCC4RDRACXX_L8_RHUMdztTAALIRAAPEI-207       GSM2475318
```

The column names of my counts table is a simplified version of the "title" column in "samples". How can I replace the column names in my counts table as the "id" names in "samples"?

So, my counts table should look like this:

```
                                GSM2475317                 GSM2475318
gene1                                    0                          0
gene2                                   97                         74
```

Comment: What is the connecting link between the 2 DF? I guess the link must be between `title` from the second and the column names from the first DF. But that is just a guess. Your data should be a bit less sparse.

Comment: It's not clear to me how to tell what goes where. I don't see any clear link between the column names you show in `counts` with the strings in `samples$title`. And your desired result with the same placeholder column name repeated twice doesn't help.

Comment: Like, is the number in `X140624_` supposed to correspond to `140718_`? Your example has no correspondence there. Your example always has `I266` in both, is that always the case or does it need to be checked? The next section, it's not clear if that's supposed to correspond or not. Maybe a partial string match anywhere? Or maybe it's supposed to be the beginning or end of the `title` string? I have no idea. etc.

Comment: @GregorThomas the amount of rows in my DF were too many - there are hundreds of them. So I only copied the first 2 lines, sorry for the confusion. The simplified name in `counts` has the unique values of the title names.

Comment: Yes, the issue wasn't that you didn't share you *whole* data, it's that you didn't choose an example that makes the problem clear. Using 2-5 rows/columns as an example is great. Please choose those rows specifically to illustrate the problem. Instead of picking the first 2 rows from `samples` or random rows from `samples`, share the 2 rows of `samples` that actually correspond to the 2 columns from `counts` that you show. And also throw in a couple other rows from `samples` that don't match. Then we can begin to see what parts of the strings need to match and what parts don't matter.

Comment: It would also help if you would describe in word exactly what parts of the strings need to match. Currently we can't help because it is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

To replace the name of a dataframe you can use the function `colnames()`

If your dataframes were in the same order, would be as easy as `colnames(counts) <- samples$id`

But if the problem is that you have a different order in the two dataframes, you have two options:

1. Sort the rows from samples to obtain the same order that the column names have in counts and then apply the function that I have put before
2. Obtain the order of the rows in samples regarding the columns. I will now paste some code to explain this one, the problem is that I was not sure about how was the simplification of the name done, so I just assumed that the common part is the numbers from the end of each name, if it's different you will have to change the regular expressions from `sub`

```
# Generating the data
counts <-
  data.frame(
    X140624_I266.4MKD.L1.201 = c(0, 97),
    X140624_I266.4MKD.L1.207 = c(0, 60),
    X140624_I266.4MKD.L1.202 = c(0, 74),
    X140624_I266.4MKD.L1.215 = c(0, 23)
  )
rownames(counts) <- c("gene1", "gene2")

sample <-
  data.frame(
    title = c(
      "140718_I266_FCC4RDRACXX_L1_RHUMdztTAAKSRAAPEI-215",
      "140718_I266_FCC4RDRACXX_L8_RHUMdztTAALIRAAPEI-207",
      "140718_I266_FCC4RDRACXX_L1_RHUMdztTAAKSRAAPEI-202",
      "140718_I266_FCC4RDRACXX_L8_RHUMdztTAALIRAAPEI-201"
    ),
    id = c("GSM2475317", "GSM2475318", "GSM2475319", "GSM2475320")
  )

# Extract the last number in each column in counts
index_count <- sub(".*\\.", "", colnames(counts))

# Extract the last number from each sample
index_sample <- sub(".*\\-", "", sample$title)

match(index_count, index_sample)

colnames(counts) <- sample[match(index_sample, index_count), "id"]
```

With this code the tables will be:

- counts:

|  | X140624_I266.4MKD.L1.201 | X140624_I266.4MKD.L1.207 | X140624_I266.4MKD.L1.202 | X140624_I266.4MKD.L1.215 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| gene1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| gene2 | 97 | 60 | 74 | 23 |

- sample:

| title | id |
| --- | --- |
| 140718_I266_FCC4RDRACXX_L1_RHUMdztTAAKSRAAPEI-215 | GSM2475317 |
| 140718_I266_FCC4RDRACXX_L8_RHUMdztTAALIRAAPEI-207 | GSM2475318 |
| 140718_I266_FCC4RDRACXX_L1_RHUMdztTAAKSRAAPEI-202 | GSM2475319 |
| 140718_I266_FCC4RDRACXX_L8_RHUMdztTAALIRAAPEI-201 | GSM2475320 |

- counts after colname change:

|  | GSM2475320 | GSM2475318 | GSM2475319 | GSM2475317 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| gene1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| gene2 | 97 | 60 | 74 | 23 |

Comment: Thank you! I will try this out - the problem is I have about 400-500 of these samples I need to loop through